# Can I parse data using JSON.parse() in javascript variable passed in current URL using PHP globals like ($_GET, $_POST)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to directly get the data in javascript variable using PHP $_GET method and then parse the data as a json object.

I can get it using PHP and then convert it into string but it is not providing me JSON like structure. All I am getting is a continuous string.

I have converted the data using json_decode in PHP and converted it to one single string and then passed the string to JS variable.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($_GET['data'], true );

$val = "";
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " : ";
    $arr = $value;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $v) {
        echo $v . " ";
        $val .= $v . " | ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var l = "<?= $val ?>";
console.log(l); // This is a string
var json = "<?php echo $_GET['data'] ?>"; // Error Code
var jd = json.parse(json);
</script>
```

SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier // I am getting this error

Comment: you should **never** mix PHP and js - they're executed differently and can result in unexpected errors. Research AJAX

Comment: Can we see the page code, and an example of the data you pass on the querystring please

Answer (score 0):

You should put the JSON in single quotes, because double quotes are used in the JSON representation itself.

```
var json = '<?php echo $_GET['data'] ?>';
var jd = JSON.parse(json);
```

But there's really no need to use `JSON.parse`. JSON itself is in the correct format for a JavaScript literal, so you can just write:

```
var jd = <?php echo $_GET['data'] ?>;
```

However, it's a bad idea to insert a URL parameter directly into the JavaScript, as they might send something that isn't just JSON. So you should use `json_encode()` to regenerate the object from PHP:

```
var jd = <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never mix PHP with JavaScript.**

As said, you should be using Ajax to perform this action.
You can then apply the result into a JavaScript variable if needed.

```js
<script>
var result = '';

$.ajax({
    url: 'parse_url.php',
    type: "POST", //request type,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success:function(json){
        result = json;
    },
    error: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
});

console.log(result);
</script>
```

parse_url.php

```php
die(json_encode($_GET));
```